# Linear mapping from square matrix vector space to polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ be a vector space of all 2 dimensional square matrices and $P$ be the space of all $2^{nd}$ degree polynomials. Suppose we have a linear mapping defined as ( from here on, $0$ will denote null vectors in their respective vector spaces ):

$$(\phi (A))(x) = tr(AB+BA)+tr(AB-BA)x+tr(A+A^T)x^2$$

where $B = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2 \\ 2 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$

I want to find the nullity of $\phi$ and it's rank.

My attempt:
First, I noted that matrix trace (here, $tr$) is a linear mapping itself, which means $tr(A+B) = tr(A)+tr(B)$ and $tr(\alpha A) = \alpha tr(A)$. Then, i noted some special properties of matrix trace, such as $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$. From this property, it is immediately obvious that $tr(AB-BA)x = 0$.

This leaves us with

$$(\phi (A))(x) = tr(AB+BA)+tr(A+A^T)x^2$$
or
$$(\phi (A))(x) = 2tr(AB)+2tr(A)x^2$$ 
First, let us find the nullity of linear mapping $\phi$. By defintion, nullity is defined as
$nul(\phi)=dim(ker(\phi))$ where $ker(\phi)= \{u \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) | \phi(u) = 0 \}$

This leads u to 
$$tr(AB)+tr(A)x^2 = 0$$ 
This, of course, means $tr(AB)=0$ and $tr(A)=0$. 
Only possible solution for this is $A=0$  and so $nul(\phi) = 0$.

Are there any other solutions for this? Is there a simpler solution for this? How exactly am i supposed to find the image of this linear mapping? Is it the whole $p$ vector space?

Comment: what is $B$? Is it fixed? And a note: $tr(AB)=0=tr(A)$, in general, doesn't mean $A=0$

Comment: What is the meaning of matrix $B$ in the definition of your mapping?

Comment: @Exodd I apologize, i omitted the matrix B. Fixed now.

Comment: If $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, then $tr(AB)=tr(A)=0$, but $A\ne 0$

Comment: @Exodd That was a solution i missed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

$\phi: M_2\to P$ is alinear map that goes to a 4-dimensional vector space to a 3-dimensional one. Moreover, as you noticed, 
$$(\phi (A))(x) = 2tr(AB)+2tr(A)x^2$$
so its image is contained in a 2-dimensional vector space.

This means that the nullity has at least dimension 2 and is described by the equations $$tr(AB)=tr(A)=0$$

Its rank is at maximum 2, and it's exactly 2 since $A=I$ and $A=E_{11}$ generate two linear indipendent elements of $P$